# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code**

This is my code:

```
 def bestIndividual(hof, X, y):
        # Get the best individual
       
        maxAccurcy = 0.0
        for individual in hof:
            if(individual.fitness.values > maxAccurcy):
                maxAccurcy = individual.fitness.values
                _individual = individual
    
        _individualHeader = [list(X)[i] for i in range(
            len(_individual)) if _individual[i] == 1]
        return _individual.fitness.values, _individual, _individualHeader
    



individual = [1 for i in range(len(X.columns))]
print("Accuracy with all features: \t" +
      str(getFitness(individual, X, y)) + "\n")

# apply genetic algorithm
hof = geneticAlgorithm(X, y, n_pop, n_gen)

# select the best individual
accuracy, individual, header = bestIndividual(hof, X, y)
```

**Error**
I'm getting this error please help, using Python 3.8.5
How do I fix this, individual is a tuple and maxAccuracy is float

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gaFeatureSelection.py", line 121, in <module>
    accuracy, individual, header = bestIndividual(hof, X, y)
  File "gaFeatureSelection.py", line 78, in bestIndividual
    if(individual.fitness.values > maxAccurcy):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: Given that the operands are a tuple and a float, what result do you expect from `>`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible ___Runnable___ Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you have lots of undefined variables in the code you posted.

Comment: Check the values stored in `individual.fitness.values` and `maxAccurcy`. One of them is bound to be a tuple. Change it and re-try maybe?

Comment: Do you want to check if `any()` of the `individual.fitness.values` greater than `maxAccurcy`, or perhaps `all()` of them?

Comment: The code works in python 2, in python3 it giving this error

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote first of all as the code you provided wasn't executable therefore I can't guarantee you that this solution might work because I don't have grounds to test out solution still ...:... apart from that, you can still try bellow methods.

First way: initializing in int format itself.

```
def bestIndividual(hof, X, y):
        # Get the best individual
       
        maxAccurcy = 0 # initialized in int
        for individual in hof:
            if(individual.fitness.values > maxAccurcy):
                maxAccurcy = individual.fitness.values
                _individual = individual 
    
        _individualHeader = [list(X)[i] for i in range(
            len(_individual)) if _individual[i] == 1]
        return _individual.fitness.values, _individual, _individualHeader
    



individual = [1 for i in range(len(X.columns))]
print("Accuracy with all features: \t" +
      str(getFitness(individual, X, y)) + "\n")

# apply genetic algorithm
hof = geneticAlgorithm(X, y, n_pop, n_gen)

# select the best individual
accuracy, individual, header = bestIndividual(hof, X, y)
```

> Blockquote float and tuple aren't comparable , if above snippet doesn't work then either you have to covert tuples to float    using Method : " join() + float() + str() + generator expression " or vise versa

for example

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate working of
# Convert tuple to float
# using join() + float() + str() + generator expression
  
# initialize tuple
test_tup = (4, 56)
  
# printing original tuple 
print("The original tuple : " + str(test_tup))
  
# Convert tuple to float
# using join() + float() + str() + generator expression
res = float('.'.join(str(ele) for ele in test_tup))
  
# printing result
print("The float after conversion from tuple is : " + str(res))
#Output :
#The original tuple : (4, 56)
#The float after conversion from tuple is : 4.56
#enter code here
```